# Best book/ tutorial to learn/implement web services using java, xml and spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am a newbie to web-services. What is a good way to learn web-services implementation using java, xml and spring? Are there any good books which cover this topic in good width?
Or, are there any online resources, tutorials, etc.?

Also, what would be good projects to understand this hands-on?

Any recommendations>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally learned Web Services concepts without books, so my opinions may be biased, but I don't think books would help much in the beginning. Once you get to some intermediate state where you need to study security, SOA, etc, maybe books would help.

I needed to get an intern up to speed on Web Services, so I made him implement a two-player game of [Reversi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi) using Web Services as the business logic layer with SQL Server underneath it. The UI layer was a desktop executable hitting the service.

You can do something like that using Axis2 and Swing. Once you've built the first UI, you can then try to consume the same service using .NET/Ruby/jQuery or something too to demonstrate the interoperability.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Spring in Action Second Edition Cover]

[Spring in Action Second Edition](http://www.manning.com/walls3/) has a fair bit of information about using Spring and web services with examples. It worked for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've never read this, but it has good reviews on Amazon: [Java Web Services: Up and Running](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059652112X)

[alt text http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51OXWAyftOL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51OXWAyftOL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I own this book but haven't read it: [SOA Using Java Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130449687)

[image]

Comment: hey, thanks for these books, I have also looked at amazon.com's books. But, my confusion is more of whether these books would do a good job in actually teaching implementation and hands-on kind of stuff or would they just bog me down in all theoretical stuff.

Also, any ideas on any good projects for hands-on experience?

Answer (score 0):

The Java SOA Cookbook is very good - but it does not really cover Spring.

The Spring Recipes book is pretty good at explaining How-To do things in Spring.

Comment: from the comments on amazon, it seems like this book is more geared towards experienced programmers. I am more of a total newbie to web services programming, and am trying to find good resource for getting started and then go build on that. Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I found books okay, but in the end I used spring web services and it was such a breeze. Highly recommend the reference manual. It has a great introduction on the approach spring web services has taken with the contract first approach and why it is recommended.

http://static.springframework.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/index.html

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Some IDEs have web service wizards and projects that take you through setting up a service.  They might not be a great way to learn about web services by themselves, but you'll be exposed to some key terms and ideas that can help you build a vocabulary and starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need spring or XML to do web services. Just a simple jetty and stringtemplate will allow you concentrate on the java and web service stuff, and allow you to refactor your code easily in the ide.

I expect to be down voted by the spring fanatics, but honestly, it's whet you want to be doing!