# good resource to study web services in java?

Tags: java, web-services

Does any body know of any good links to sites which have tutorials to develop web services and implementation of SOAP/ JAX-rS, REstFul web services?
I am new to web services..please help me out with regards to that..
Thank you very much for your time.

Best Regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119838/how-to-learn-java-webservices

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827071/best-book-tutorial-to-learn-implement-web-services-using-java-xml-and-spring

Answer (score 0):

In general implementation is easy. More difficult is identifying the services, their granularity etc ;-)

From the Java EE 6 tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html
Other: http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html